# Problem for line breaks (\n) with gtsummary functions

Tags: line-breaks, gtsummary

I have a problem trying to include line breaks into arguments of `gtsummary` functions, as `statistic` argument of `tbl_summary()` or `update` for `modify_header()`. It's a bit strange because it always have worked until now, and the package documentation indicates that this the way to do so...

Here a reproducible example :

```
## loading packages ##
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

## gtsummary table ##
trial %>% tbl_summary(include = c("trt","stage","grade"),
                      by = "trt",
                      statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}% \n ({n})", # \n does not pass "({n})" to next line...
                      missing = "no") %>%
  modify_header(update =list(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}** \n ({p}%, \n N = {n})"), # and here as well...
                text_interpret = "md")
```

[gtsummary cross table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXTVq.jpg)

Does the problem uniquely come from my computer ? Could it be due to a recent package update ?

Comment: For gt tables, the \n must be preceded by TWO speaces

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg thanks for the quick answer (and for the wonderful gtsummary package) ! Actually adding the double space before "\n" made it work for _modify_header()_, but not for the _statistic_ argument of _tbl_summary()_. I've done it often and never had this issue (even with a simple space), that's why I was a bit confused...

Comment: And sorry I've just seen on your github that you're currently working on ! I will wait no problem, I'm not in a hurry at all  :-)

Comment: I am not at a computer to give a full response, but I think for line breaks in gt table cells, you can use either `"  \n"` or `"<br>"` but you need to convert the gtsummary table to gt, then apply the markdown formatting, like this: `tbl_summary(...) |> as_gt() |> gt::fmt_markdown(columns = everything())`

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks for the tips ! Problem is that I wanted to make it with gtsummary cause I've created my own function for cross tables based on `tbl_summary()`, and I improve formating only at a second step, using or `as_gt()` or `as_flex_table()` depending on cases (love gt but unfortunately incompatible with Rmarkdown docx output...). Anyway I can also manage it with flextable, using `as_paragraph()` into `value` argument of `compose()` for cell content, it will just be a little bit longer when creating personal formating functions (already did it for header part and had to use regex).